# Deleting our database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

What can we add to our database such that if we delete something accidentally we'll be able to recover it? Is there something that we can do? I find out that our only option is if we have backups or we have a special software to recover the data, but is there something we can add and prevent this accidental deletion?

Comment: what type of database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Use Salesforce, they have `undelete` feature ;-) They don't have backups, though... And it is not really SQL, nor a database as such... But still, they have `undelete`.

Comment: Frequent backups ...

Comment: Do all INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE using Stored Procedures to check for validity and don't grant delete/drop rights for endusers running ad hoc-SQL. And run regular backups :-)

Comment: Use full recovery mode

Comment: But, seriously, you can try to set up [Audit Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc280386.aspx). In addition to normal frequent backups and properly restricted access rights for users.

Comment: Once I have accidentally run a script to delete all records from all tables on production database. I had simple recovery so I reverted to nightly backup. Perhaps something like this worries you?

Answer (score 1):

you may have a shadow database with the same structure of main DB. in main DB write triggers for delete operation in which the record is inserted to shadow DB after deletion from main.

Microsoft semantic logging is also a powerful technique to work with such situations.